# 30.03.2016 throws BindException with LocalDate

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a strange behavior. I have a form that submit 2 date fields in german dateformat (dd.mm.yyyy). The entity fields are from type LocalDate.
Everything works as expected, but not in february.
If the user enter a day of month greater then 28 (30.march, 29.april, 29.may..), the spring mvc application throws a BindException.

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'activity' on field 'beginsOnDate': rejected value [31.03.2016]; codes [methodInvocation.activity.beginsOnDate,methodInvocation.beginsOnDate,methodInvocation.java.time.LocalDate,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [activity.beginsOnDate,beginsOnDate]; arguments []; default message [beginsOnDate]]; default message [Property 'beginsOnDate' threw exception; nested exception is java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31']
Field error in object 'activity' on field 'endsOnDate': rejected value [31.03.2016]; codes [methodInvocation.activity.endsOnDate,methodInvocation.endsOnDate,methodInvocation.java.time.LocalDate,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [activity.endsOnDate,endsOnDate]; arguments []; default message [endsOnDate]]; default message [Property 'endsOnDate' threw exception; nested exception is java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31']
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:113) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.doFilter(DandelionFilter.java:138) [dandelion-core-0.10.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.gzip.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:85) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

The exception is throw in spring 4.1 also in 4.2.

If i enter a date below the 28 of month, f.e. 13.05.2016. everything works fine.

regards
Rizzi

Update #1 - Controller Code from Demo Spring Boot Application to reproduce

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes(types = {Activity.class})
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(Model model) {
        Activity activity = new Activity();
        activity.setBeginsOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        activity.setEndsOn(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15));
        model.addAttribute(activity);
        return "demo";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@ModelAttribute Activity activity) {
        System.out.println(activity.getBeginsOnDate());
        System.out.println(activity.getEndsOnDate());
        return "demo";
    }
}
```

Entity Code:

```
public class Activity {

private LocalDateTime beginsOn, endsOn;

@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private LocalDate beginsOnDate, endsOnDate;
@DateTimeFormat(style = "-S")
private LocalTime beginsOnTime, endsOnTime;

public LocalDateTime getBeginsOn() {
    return beginsOn;
}

public void setBeginsOn(LocalDateTime beginsOn) {
    this.beginsOn = beginsOn;
    if (beginsOn != null) {
        this.beginsOnDate = beginsOn.toLocalDate();
        this.beginsOnTime = beginsOn.toLocalTime();
    }
}

public LocalTime getBeginsOnTime() {
    return beginsOnTime;
}

public void setBeginsOnTime(LocalTime beginsOnTime) {
    this.beginsOnTime = beginsOnTime;
    if (beginsOnTime != null) {
        beginsOn.with(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, beginsOnTime.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        beginsOn.with(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, beginsOnTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR));
    }
}

public LocalDateTime getEndsOn() {
    return endsOn;
}

public void setEndsOn(LocalDateTime endsOn) {
    this.endsOn = endsOn;
    if (endsOn != null) {
        this.endsOnDate = endsOn.toLocalDate();
        this.endsOnTime = endsOn.toLocalTime();
    }
}

public LocalTime getEndsOnTime() {
    return endsOnTime;
}

public void setEndsOnTime(LocalTime endsOnTime) {
    this.endsOnTime = endsOnTime;
    if (endsOnTime != null) {
        endsOn.with(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, endsOnTime.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        endsOn.with(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, endsOnTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR));
    }
}

public LocalDate getBeginsOnDate() {

    return beginsOnDate;
}

public void setBeginsOnDate(LocalDate beginsOnDate) {
    this.beginsOnDate = beginsOnDate;
    if (beginsOnDate != null) {
        if (beginsOn == null)
            beginsOn = LocalDateTime.of(beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.YEAR), beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR), beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0);
        else {
            beginsOn.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            beginsOn.with(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
            beginsOn.with(ChronoField.YEAR, beginsOnDate.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
        }
    }
}

public LocalDate getEndsOnDate() {
    return endsOnDate;
}

public void setEndsOnDate(LocalDate endsOnDate) {
    this.endsOnDate = endsOnDate;
    if (endsOnDate != null) {
        if (endsOn == null)
            endsOn = LocalDateTime.of(endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.YEAR), endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR),  endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0);
        else {
            endsOn.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            endsOn.with(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR,  endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
            endsOn.with(ChronoField.YEAR, endsOnDate.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
        }
    }
}

}
```

activityForm.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>BindException Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>BindException Demo Page</b>
<form id="activityForm" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${activity}" action="#" method="post" th:method="post">
    <label>BeginsOnDate:</label>
    <input type="text"
           th:field="*{beginsOnDate}"
           th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('beginsOnDate')} ? 'field-error'" />
    <br />
    <label>EndsOnDate:</label>
    <input type="text"
           th:field="*{endsOnDate}"
           th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('endsOnDate')} ? 'field-error'" />
    <br />
    <input th:type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to Spring.

Comment: @RizziCR can you post your controller's code?

Comment: Add the code from the demo application

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that this is not a bug. After playing sometime with the demo application, i find the real problem.
The problem was between display and chair. I'm not realize that i have to reassign a date time variable when working with the "with" method of a date time variable.